# error running geopandas coverd_by doumenttion example

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas, shapely

I am running the Geopandas cover_by  to check if each geometry of GeoSeries is covered by a single geometry example [here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.covered_by.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.covered_by). but I got this error :

```
NotImplementedError: covered_by is only implemented for pygeos, not shapely
```

I tried to upgrade shapely and geopandas to the last version but the error still there.

I use MacBook and anaconda for virtual environment with python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone faces the same situation, solution is to install **`pygeos`**.